# For loop... Forever

Tags: ruby, loops, optimization

I have a for loop that I would like to have increment forever.

My code:

```
for a in (0...Float::INFINITY).step(2)
    puts a
end
```

Output:

```
0.0
2.0
4.0
Etc. Always with "#{a}.0"
```

Is there any way to express infinity as an integer, so that the output does not have a `.0` at the end without preforming any operations on the contents of the loop?

**Addendum**

Could you also explain how your loop works? I am trying to find the most efficient solution, because since this loop will be iterating infinity, a few milliseconds shaved off will improve the performance greatly.

**Also...**

I will accept the solution that takes to shortest time to run to 1000000

According to <s>`benchmark` both @Sefan and the `while` loop answers take the same ammount of time</s>`Fruity` the `while` loop answers take a bit shorter, with the `for` loop answers in second, but the multiple `loop do` answers take far longer.

<s>Since the reason why is out of the scope of this question, I have created another question that addresses why some loops are faster than others (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088764/peddle-to-the-metal-faster-loop-faster).</s>

Comment: "[S]ince this loop will be iterating infinity, a few milliseconds shaved off will improve the performance greatly"--I don't get this. An infinite process will never end. Difference in performance per iteration will not make any difference.

Comment: @sawa This is a very simplified version of my code, I am trying to check each number that the loop reaches for a certain characteristic, and I would like the loop to check numbers as quickly as possible. So if it takes a millisecond less for each number that is checked, after it checks 1 mil numbers it will have saved a second, and it will be checking trillions of numbers.

Comment: @sawa It will be terminated at some point. There is no loop that will actually run infinity, because for all intents and purposes any infinite loop will be terminated.

Comment: @shivam's answer is a while loop so your update does not make much sense. As for Stefan's answer I kind of explained the reasoning in my answer.

Comment: @engineersmnky Sorry! I didn't mean to say the `while` loop answers, I meant the `loop do` answers. Editing now. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Okay so shivrams answer is the fastest and it is probably due to the fact that `while` is a ruby keyword and leverages the underlying C code sort of as a wrapper. This means there is very little interpretation needed to execute the code. Stefans answer is the second fastest because it is using an Enumerator. As for the nitty gritty specifics maybe
@JörgWMittag will swing back around as he generally has excellent insight into these things.

Comment: @engineersmnky In my tests which I just ran it seems that the `while true` solution is barely faster (like <1%) than the `for a in 0.step(2)` whereas the `loop do` solution is far slower. Why?

Comment: while and for...in are all keywords and function a little differently than standard Object methods. I would assume the results have to do with a lack of overhead between Ruby and the underlying C code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Numeric#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Numeric.html#method-i-step) without passing a *limit*:

```
0.step(by: 2) { |i| puts i }
```

Output:

```
0
2
4
6
...
```

You can also build your own `Enumerator`:

```
step2 = Enumerator.new do |y|
  a = 0
  loop do
    y << a
    a += 2
  end
end

step2.each { |i| puts i }
```

Comment: @thesecretmaster you can write `for i in 0.step(by: 2)`

Comment: Any easy way to do this in Ruby 2.0's [`Numeric#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step)?

Comment: @WandMaker you could use `Integer#upto` instead e.g. `0.upto(Float::INFINITY) { |i| puts i * 2}` This will have the same output where as using `Numeric#step` will cause the values to be converted to `Floats` if you use `Float::INFINITY` as the limit. Either that or create your own `Enumerator` which in this case is fairly easy as well.

Comment: @WandMaker I've added an example with a custom `Enumerator`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `while true` for that:

```
puts a = 0
puts a+=2 while true
```

BTW,

> Is there any way to express infinity as an integer

**NO**

Comment: Will this loop check if `true == true` after each iteration?

Comment: after each iteration it will check if condition is `true` - YES. Does it check by `true == true`? - NO.

Comment: The output starts with `2`, i.e. `0` is omitted.

Comment: printing `0` while assignment fixes this. Though not a smart solution.

Comment: Perhaps `a = -2; puts a+= 2 while true`

Comment: Wow, coming back to this question I feel like an idiot for not thinking "Wait... infinity as an integer...? What? That makes no sense"

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'bigdecimal'
(0..BigDecimal('Infinity')).step(2).each{ |n| puts n }
```

OR

```
require 'bigdecimal'
for a in (0...BigDecimal::INFINITY).step(2)
  puts a
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what the loop method is designed for. `loop` has no condition for which to run. It will run indefinitely and the only way to exit is to use the keyword `break`. (or raise a `StopIteration`)

```
a = 0
loop { puts a += 2}
```

This loop will be infinite as there is no `break` specified.

`break` can be specified very similarly to how the other answers use the while condition if needed:

```
a = 0 
loop do 
  puts a += 2
  break if a > 1_000_000
end
```

This `loop` will now exit once the value of `a` exceeds 1M.

That being said @Stefan's answer is more efficient as it does not store this integral value or have to perform any additional assignment but rather the number is simply yielded from an Enumerator and discarded it afterwards. The usefulness of this becomes more a matter of your implementation and purpose for this loop.

Comment: `loop` is not a keyword, it's just a method like any other.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I apologize answer revised to *"loop method"*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr = [0]
arr.cycle(1000000) { |i| puts arr[0] +=2  }
```

If you want infinite loop, then, don't pass any parameter to `cycle`

```
arr = [0]
arr.cycle { |i| puts arr[0] +=2  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [-2]
puts a.unshift(a.shift+2) while 'loop forever'
```